# Re load Select Option Values - PHP JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a bootstrap pop-up form to add kingdom name it will appear when we select Add New option from the Kingdom list, I would like to show the newly added value in the list just after closing the popup window. My current code is given below. But It's not working. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the code behind `$('#kg_id').load()`

Comment: That is select option ID

 <select name="kg_id" id="kg_id"  data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8"  >
                            <option value="">Select here..</option>
                            <option value="a">Add new</option>
                          </select>

Comment: In the success part..  Add a functions for appending new value to the form list..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you append an option to select tag

```
//...
$('#kingdom_nameerr').html('Saved successfully');
$('#yourSelectIDonPage').append('<option value="'+someOptionID+'">'+optionSelected+'</option>');
//...
```

Comment: This is susceptible to XSS injection... When programmatically generating HTML, user input should be sanitized or an API such as the DOM or jQuery should be used to safely set properties of HTML elements.

Comment: @dana Absolutely. I agree. But the point here is that how that particular thing could be implemented. Security should be the next thing to do (which, however, isn't related with question)

Answer (score 1):

In the `success` callback, do the following:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    if (data == "1") {
        $('#kingdom_nameerr').html('Saved successfully');

        // add a new option to #kg_id
        $('<option></option>')
            .val(name)
            .text(name)
            .appendTo('#kg_id');

        // select the new option
        $('#kg_id').val(name);
    } else {
        $('#kingdom_nameerr').html('Data already exists');
    }
}
...
```